# Camera Canon pal DC95 not being able to get cd contents

Tags: video, compact-disc, camera, optical-drive

A friend of mine recorded a family event with his Canon pal DC95. This camera records to a mini cd. I saw the cd being played in the camera (which was hooked up to a tv) but when I place the cd's in my pcs cd player I see nothing.

Like if the cd had nothing on it. I tried downloading the manual of the camera (maybe I have to do something to the cd) but I can't find it online.

I really want to get the videos on the cd so I can pass them to some other friends.

Anyone know how I can achieve this? Please help me out :)

Thanks.

PS: Just a reminder. I know that the cd's contain stuff, but when I place the cd in the drive I just see a blank cd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to finalize de disc to play it in a DVD player or PC. The disc has to be inside de Camcorderwhich must be connected with the compat power adapter. Choose  Menu - disc operations- finalize - yes